# Unable to Download Secure File error in Azure DevOps Server 2019

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-server-2019

When using the "Download Secure File" task in a build pipeline I'm getting an error. This is regarding a UWP build pipeline.

```
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Download Signing Key'
##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
##[debug]=> True
##[debug]Result: True
##[section]Starting: Download Signing Key
==============================================================================
Task         : Download secure file
Description  : Download a secure file to a temporary location on the agent machine
Version      : 1.151.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=862069)
==============================================================================
##[debug]agent.TempDirectory=C:\uwpagent64\_work\_temp
##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading INPUT_SECUREFILE
##[debug]loaded 4
##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
##[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined
##[debug]check path : C:\uwpagent64\_work\_tasks\DownloadSecureFile_2a6ca863-f2ce-4f4d-8bcb-15e64608ec4b\1.151.2\task.json
##[debug]adding resource file: C:\uwpagent64\_work\_tasks\DownloadSecureFile_2a6ca863-f2ce-4f4d-8bcb-15e64608ec4b\1.151.2\task.json
##[debug]system.culture=en-US
##[debug]secureFile=3f06a897-0a76-4128-ab68-331d50693270
##[debug]System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri=http://192.168.25.5/BoardPAC%20Collection/
##[debug]SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION auth param ACCESSTOKEN = ***
##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
##[debug]secure file name for id 3f06a897-0a76-4128-ab68-331d50693270 = BoardPACWinApp_TemporaryKey.pfx
##[debug]Agent.TempDirectory=C:\uwpagent64\_work\_temp
##[debug]Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\uwpagent64\_work\_temp,BoardPACWinApp_TemporaryKey.pfx = C:\uwpagent64\_work\_temp\BoardPACWinApp_TemporaryKey.pfx
##[debug]Downloading secure file contents to: C:\uwpagent64\_work\_temp\BoardPACWinApp_TemporaryKey.pfx
##[debug]secure file ticket for id 3f06a897-0a76-4128-ab68-331d50693270 = null
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Error: Download ticket for SecureFileId 3f06a897-0a76-4128-ab68-331d50693270 not found.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Download ticket for SecureFileId 3f06a897-0a76-4128-ab68-331d50693270 not found.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: Download ticket for SecureFileId 3f06a897-0a76-4128-ab68-331d50693270 not found.
##[section]Finishing: Download Signing Key
```

**NOTE: DevOps server versions are as follows**

- Azure DevOps Server 2019 (17.153.29522.3)
- Software Version (17.153.29522.3) (AzureDevOps2019.Update1.1)
- Database service level (17.153.29522.3) (AzureDevOps2019.Update1.1)

Answer (score 0):

I have generated a test certificate from the server where my build agent runs and then added a brand new `Download secure file` task and uploaded that certificate. Now it seems to be working fine.
I also updated my VS build tools to Version 16.7. That sorted my issue.